# I've tried this piece of code to make my character fall with gravity however the character simply doesn't fall(UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: The Code used]
[image: The game when you run it(only the view not actually running)]

I've tried changing a few lines of code at the end because I believe that is what needs to be changing

Answer (score 0):

Something is not right with your VS, because your code is not corrected and there are several problems (MonoBehaviour should be green), but when Unity gets focus, it should show the errors in its console.

`movementspeed` is an int, it has not any method 'Move'.

If I were you, I add a `Rigidbody` to the `GameObject`, but if you want this way, then you'll have to apply gravity to your `transform's` Y value.